# open webpage when start nodejs server

Tags: node.js, express

I was wondering if and how i can automatically open a webpage when i start my server with nodejs

```
app.listen(app.get("PORT"), () => {
        console.log(`Servidor corriendo en http://localhost:${app.get("PORT")}`)
    })
```

I have this basic example where when i run **node start proyect** it will start the server and then i manually need to click on the console logged message or open a browser and type bla bla bla

I want to raise that web for itself like when in React we run the command **npm run start**

I tried to google it but i dont know how to search for this because i dont get any usefull info.
Thank u very much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [open](https://www.npmjs.com/package/open) to Open stuff like URLs, files, executables. Cross-platform.

```
const open = require('open');

// opens the url in the default browser 
open('http://stackoverflow.com');
```

---

UPDATE

open simplifies cross platform functionality, in node you can have access to the platform by `process.platform` and write platform specific executions

for example here is the native version in mac without using any NPM module

```
const url = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
require('child_process').exec(`open ${url}`);
```

I don't have access to a windows system to write the code for windows

Comment: Jesus, so simple ahahah. Thank u a LOT.
Anyway, is there a native way for doing this with js vanilla? or nodejs native modules?

Comment: @Programmer89 you're welcome :), I added answer of your comment's question in the post

Comment: For windows you can use "require('child_process').exec(`start ${url}`);"